# Excel - Count first time contributors

Tags: countif

What I would like to do is count the amount of first time contributors by month. So for January, there were 3 people that contributed in January for the first time, 1 in February, and 1 in March.

I wasn't sure how to write a countifs function (maybe a different function?) that would exclude those who contributed in previous months. Thanks.

```
Employee| January| February| March| Year Totals
PR      | 3      | 0       | 0    | 3
RK      | 2      | 1       | 1    | 4
JG      | 0      | 1       | 2    | 3 
ST      | 1      | 0       | 4    | 5
DM      | 0      | 0       | 2    | 2 

1st time| 3      | 1       | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Employee` is in Sheet1 A1 and the sheet is copied into Sheet2 with the data replaced from B2 to suit with:

```
=--AND(SUM(Sheet1!$A2:B2)>0,SUM(Sheet1!$A2:A2)=0)
```

then in Sheet1 in ColumnB and copied across to suit:

```
=SUM(Sheet2!B:B)
```